# List-style-image not shown for li

Tags: html, css

I am currently playing arround with customizing lists in HTML and CSS, so I tried to use custom images to be used for the `li` 'dot'.
However, it is not shown. Could someone tell me whats wrong with this code snippet?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

container > div .content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

list-div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;

}

.list-div li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  visibility: visible;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list-div li:nth-child(1){
  list-style-image: url('https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A');
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul class="items-list" id="list">
          <li>List item A</li>
          <li>List item B</li>
          <li>List item C</li>
          <li>List item D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use         `list-style-type: none;` and 
`margin-left:40px;` to `li`

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

container > div .content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

list-div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;

}

.list-div li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  visibility: visible;
  text-transform: uppercase;
list-style-type: none;
margin-left:40px;
}

.list-div li:nth-child(1){
  list-style-image: url('https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A');
list-style-position: outside;
 
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul class="items-list" id="list">
          <li>List item A</li>
          <li>List item B</li>
          <li>List item C</li>
          <li>List item D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit to your comment center `li` with `image` use as below to `.list-div li:nth-child(1)`**

```
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

container > div .content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

list-div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;

}

.list-div li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  visibility: visible;
  text-transform: uppercase;
list-style-type: none;
margin-left:40px;
}

.list-div li:nth-child(1){
background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul class="items-list" id="list">
          <li>List item A</li>
          <li>List item B</li>
          <li>List item C</li>
          <li>List item D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot:) is it possible to center the text with the image?

Comment: thanks a lot, maybe I was not clear I thought of having the text in the 'middle' of the image 'height' :)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your patience, I am a complete newbie to this:D now the first pixel of the 'highest' point of the letter is centered with the images middle height, is there a posibility to center the 'text content shape' with the image, so multiple lines of text are also centered (or better described let the image be centered with thte complete text vertically)? Like I said, newbie:D

Comment: I think: better described let the image be centered with thte complete text vertically

Comment: Yea, that's a better explanation :)